# Apache POI Style does not apply

Tags: java, apache-poi, cell

I'm trying to format the headline, but it fails and I don't know why. Below is the code, pretty simple.

And this is what I get:

[image]

The last three cells are not formatted. I tried to print the `c` but it's normal.

```
// Set Cell value in sheet
                        row.createCell(0).setCellValue("Name");
                        // Set Cell value in sheet
                        row.createCell(1).setCellValue("Surname");
                        // Set Cell value in sheet
                        row.createCell(2).setCellValue("ID");
                        // Set Cell value in sheet
                        row.createCell(3).setCellValue("Duration");

                        // Set CellStyle head to the Cells
                        Cell name = sheet.getRow(0).getCell(0);
                        name_head.setCellStyle(head);
                        Cell surname = sheet.getRow(0).getCell(1);
                        surname_head.setCellStyle(head);
                        Cell id_head = sheet.getRow(0).getCell(2);
                        id_head.setCellStyle(head);
                        Cell duration = sheet.getRow(0).getCell(3);
                        duration_haed.setCellStyle(head);

                        // Set Cell value
                        for (int c = 0; c < daysInMonth; c++) {

                            row.createCell(c + 4).setCellValue(c + 1);
                            Cell header = sheet.getRow(0).getCell(c + 1);
                            // Set CellStyle head
                            header.setCellStyle(head);

                        }
```

Does anyone have an idea how to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The cell numbering is incorrect here:

```
Cell header = sheet.getRow(0).getCell(c + 1);
```

It should be:

```
Cell header = sheet.getRow(0).getCell(c + 4);
```